# Escape forward slash in MySQL in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to connect to MYSQL from C#(ASP.NET Web API) and run an SQL. The dynamic input param for the SQL contains forward slash. The query returns 0 records, even though data is present for the input. Tried replacing the slash with double slash as well and that did not work either. (`empName.Replace("/","//")`)

```
string query = "select * from employee where empName = @empName";
string empName = "abc/abc";
using (DbCommand cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(query))
{
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "empName", DbType.String, empName);
    using (IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(cmd))
    {
    }
}
```

Can you pls suggest me on how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape `/`, especially in a parameter value. Does it work for values without a `/` in them?

Comment: Slashes shouldn't bother you, especially that kind of slash..  Do you get any exception or just an empty result set? And also I would sugger using DataTable/DataView instead of DataReader

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Yes. it works for values without a /.

Comment: @llouk - Not exceptions. Just empty result set. Can you pls elaborate more on DataTable?

Comment: I recommend that to use [MySQL official fully-managed ADO.NET driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "empName", DbType.String, empName);
```

to this:

```
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@empName", DbType.String, empName);
```